# Not able to see current time in DateBox of GWT

Tags: gwt, datepicker, timestamp, datebox

I am using DateBox widget to set the date, but when I select any date from the date picker, I could only see the date,month,year. I need to capture **current time in the datebox as well**.

My current code is:
DateBox endDate = new DateBox();

What I see on screen is (after selecting any date,say 15th Feb,2014 from the picker):
2014 Feb 15 12:00:00

**What I need is** (current timestamp at the time of choosing date):
e.g 2014 Feb 15 **10:45:20**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Wouldn't be better to add additional control to the time ? In date  picker you cannot choose times anyway.

Comment: You let a user choose a date, but you set a time without asking a user? This is strange.

Comment: Also remember that your users can be in different time zones. So 1 pm for one user is the same moment in time as 4 pm for another. In fact, it can be January 15th in one place, and already January 16th in another.